# Create a bar plot with four levels of information

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's explore an example with the well known `mpg` dataset:

- First level is the index, let's say `model_year`.
- Second level is the quantitative variable which in this case is a simple count.
- Third level is a categorical variable. In our example, that would be the `origin`.

---

At this point I am expecting to see a regular `countplot` composed of indexes, bars and colors. Pretty standard!

```py
import seaborn as sns
mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
sns.countplot(x='model_year', data=mpg, hue='origin')
```

[image]

---

Ok! So what do I mean by "four levels of information"?
Here comes the actual question.

Let's say I want to `stack` the bars with the count **per cylinder**. In other words, each **segment** of the bar would represent the amount of produced cars for a **specific number of cylinders**.

For instance, for the year `70` the `usa` (blue bar) would have two segments (of 22 cars, 18 had 8 cylinders and 4 had 6 cylinders). Europe and Japan would have only one segment, since only 4 cylinders cars were produced in these countries, in that year.

```
mpg.groupby(['model_year', 'origin', 'cylinders'])['mpg'].count()
 
origin  cylinders
europe  4             5
japan   4             2
usa     6             4
        8            18
Name: mpg, dtype: int64
```

It is worth mentioning that the identification strategy (hatched maybe?) of the fourth information level should be consistent along the plot (equal for the same amount of cylinders) and a second legend will be necessary.

---

How can I achieve this with pandas and matplotlib, preferably without additional modules?

Comment: The Seaborn way to do this is to create multiple subplots via `sns.catplot(kind='count', x=' model_year', data=mpg, hue='origin', col='cylinder')`. Note that stacked bars are hard to compare. Seaborn's issue tracker refers to a.o. this article: [Stacked Bars Are the Worst](https://eagereyes.org/techniques/stacked-bars-are-the-worst)

Comment: I understand your point and can definitely relate to it. But I can't avoid reasoning that if you have a binary categorical variable as your fourth level of information, a stacked bar plot might be a valid visualization approach. This being the case or only for "academic" purposes, is it possible to do it?